# Updating text after button click with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am exploring React.js, and I am trying to do something fairly simple.  I would like to update the text of a certain portion of my web app when a user successfully submits their email.

What I have so far:

```
var SignupForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {email: ''};
  },

  render: function() {
    var email = this.state.value;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="email" className="input_field" ref="email" value={email} />

        <a href="#" className="button" onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Request Invite</a>
      </div>
    )
  },

  saveAndContinue: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    // Get values via this.refs

    email = this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value

    request = $.ajax({ 
          url: "/store", 
          type: "post", success:function(data){
            this.setState({email: data})
          }, 
          data: {'email': email} ,beforeSend: function(data){console.log(data);} 
    });

  }
});

React.render(<SignupForm/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

The text that I want to update is in an html element like so:

```
<h1 class="home-two-question">This is the text!</h1>
```

I want to update it to:

```
<h1 class="home-two-question">You entered the text!</h1>
```

after the email has been successfully submitted.  Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: is the `h1` part of another react component ? or just outside react components ?

Comment: it's outside right now, but if I put it in the react components would that help?

Comment: Yeah, you want your <h1> as another react component. React manages the elements state(ish) (and thus the text inside of it)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest placing all elements in React components.

You can place it in another component and establish a communication between components or place in one component.

The below is a case where h1 is in the same component.

Add a ref attribute like this

```
<h1 class="..." ref="myh1"></h1>
```

in componentDidMount the h1 reference can be stored like this (syntax
differs based on react version)

```
componentDidMount: function () {
  this.myh1 = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myh1);
}
```

now that you have a reference you can update it from anywhere like this

```
$(this.myh1).html(...);
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way to update this with state?  Wouldn't the jquery .html be slower?

Comment: AFAIK, this is a better way and no it won't be slower. If you don't like it you can still write in vanilla JS to it `this.myh1.innerHTML=..`